# check for child element, hide parent if child exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have tried this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#title_article:not(:has(>hr:first-child))').hide();
});
</script>
```

---

But never shows..

---

```
<div id="title_article">
    <span style="padding-left:121px;">Article | </span>
    <span class="entry-date"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></span>
</div>
```

Seeking to check for child element of `<hr>` if `<hr>` exists hide parent or `#title_article`

`<hr>` would not be within `<div id="title_article"></div>` but below:

```
<!-- page content -->

    <div id="title_article></div>
    <hr>

<!-- page content -->
```

Comment: No.. I want to hide the parent element if the child element is <hr>

Comment: `<hr>` is a self closing tag, `<hr></hr>` is invalid markup

Comment: do everyone a favor and get better organized when setting criteria and defining problem statements in your questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

> Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.

You have to do something like:

```
if ($('#title_article').next('hr').length)
    $('#title_article').hide();
```

In your example, `<hr>` is not a child element of `#title_article`, but a sibling.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

 if($("#title_article").next("hr").length==0)

    $("#title_article").hide()

});
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/prollygeek/57gcx6or/3/

Edit:
Use `.siblings()`

Comment: what does "this" mean in the context?

Comment: Thanks but the <hr> would be below #title_article not within div element id #title_article

Comment: @CaptainRon then use siblings , .siblings()

Comment: Thanks; but it will always hide; see updated jsfiddle. http://fiddle.jshell.net/57gcx6or/1/ the idea is that if <hr> is not below it will show.

Comment: Depending on your HTML structure, you might also want to match only when the <hr> is the immediate next sibling. In that case, you could use `.next("hr")` instead. (as Deimoks answered)

Answer (score 1):

### You could use the [children](http://api.jquery.com/children/) function jQuery has to offer.

#### Try it in this context:

```
if($('#title_article').children('hr').length > 0) {
    $('#title_article').hide();
 }
```

#### Or this:

```
if($('#title_article').children('hr').length != 0) {
    $('#title_article').hide();
 }
```

### You could also use the [parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) function

#### Try it in this context:

```
$('#title_article hr').parent().hide();
```

This will hide every `#title_article` that has an `hr` in it.